# SMTP connect failed error

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am trying for hours to solve the issue with no success.

```
2015-06-17 15:05:56 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 PSS21.win.hostgator.com
2015-06-17 15:05:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO forexyahoofinance.mario26tech.com
2015-06-17 15:05:56 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-PSS21.win.hostgator.com Hello [192.185.6.40] 250-SIZE 31457280 250-AUTH LOGIN CRAM-MD5 250 OK
2015-06-17 15:05:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2015-06-17 15:05:56 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2015-06-17 15:05:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: bWFyaW90ZWM=
2015-06-17 15:05:56 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2015-06-17 15:05:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: bUFyaW9AMjgxMA==
2015-06-17 15:05:56 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 Authentication failed
2015-06-17 15:05:56 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 Authentication failed
2015-06-17 15:05:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2015-06-17 15:05:56 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 Service closing transmission channel
2015-06-17 15:05:56 SMTP connect() failed.
```

```
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail -> IsSMTP();
$mail -> SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail -> SMTPAuth = true;
$mail -> CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail -> Host = 'sns41.win.hostgator.com'; //nameserver ,i tried ip also.
$mail -> Username = "*****"; //hostgator username
$mail -> Password = '*****'; //hostgator pass

$mail -> SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail -> Port = '465';

$mail -> FromName = $from_name;
$mail -> SetFrom = $fromEmail;
$mail -> AddAddress($toEmail);
$mail -> AddAddress('nikolaou_marios@hotmail.com',"Reply");
$mail -> addReplyTo("marios.nikolaou87@gmail.com", "Information");

$mail -> IsHTML(true);
$mail -> Subject = $subject;
$mail -> Body = $message;
$mail -> Send();


} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //rror messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Error messages from anything else!
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your Authentication once because Authentication failed error in log

Comment: confirmed that your username/password are correct?

Comment: Did you verify this is the server for YOUR server? Just because you used the nameserver doesn't mean that's your domain's IP. I'd base it on the ping and double check your credentials.

Comment: I have checked username and password for the hosting plan that i pay yearly.I used also smtp.gmail.com for host and enabled pop in my gmail account.

Comment: It does just look like normal auth failure. See those `CLIENT -> SERVER` parts ending with `=`? That's your user ID and password in plain text, base64-encoded. You might want to change them.

Comment: SOLVED !!! I contacted hostgator and they gave me the correct host name,username and password.Also AddAddress function SHOULD BE addAddress.Thank you all for your support.